# How to detect and display a page only for IE?

Tags: theme-development, browser-compatibility

I have a theme that does not work in IE so I would like to be able to detect the browser and redirect to a "sorry this doesn't work for your browser" type or what ever solution you guys can suggest for this.

Any ideas on the best way to go about this?

Comment: Use the fingerprint returned by `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and issue a `wp_redirect()` to a location of your choosing, other than using `wp_redirect()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect this question has nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: it's a wordpress site? I am going to create a another page in wordpress for ie? I figured maybe there was a custom function or something to do it? So how does this have nothing to do with wordpress?

Comment: Afaik there's also `$GLOBALS['is_IE'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code to check if it's IE ([original source](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/how_to_detect_internet_explorer_with_php.xml))...

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
?>
```

You'll have to hook it up with an action and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

WP defines global `$is_IE` variable for you and appropriate hook would be `template_redirect`.

Something like this:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'if_ie');

function if_ie() {

    global $is_IE;

    if($is_IE) {

        // code goes here
    }

    die; // stop execution and not proceed to theme template
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also, you can accomplish this using CSS only by having a style sheet for internet explorer.

In your header you can have this line:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <![endif]-->
```

which will point to your ie.css stylesheet. The code basically says "If the browser is less than or equal to interent explorer 8 (meaning 7 or 6 or 5...) then use this style sheet...

the other style sheets will also be used, but you use the ie.css rules to override the other rules. From there  you can do several things. I would tackle this by having a hidden div with some text in it that has your message in it. like this:

```
#hiddendiv /* hides it */



{

    position: fixed;

    left: 999999px; 

    height:1px; 

}
```

And then in your ie.css you can hide all of your other divs the same way and make the hidden div unhidden with really big text and a white background.

This solution is probably less buggy and has a little more flexibility because you can choose which version of IE you want to target.